# Creating Three Qubit Cluster Linear Cluster State (maybe a phase issue) (Qiskit)

Tags: qiskit, cluster-states

I am creating a three-qubit linear cluster state as defined in the following paper: [paper link](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.2587). This circuit is quite simple to implement using various libraries. I'm utilizing qiskit to construct the circuit, and I've replaced the Hadamard gates with y-rotations of angle theta/2. My goal is to prepare the following state: |000> + |001> + |010> - |011> + |100> + |101> - |110> + |111> (normalization coefficients are not a concern).

Here's the code I'm using:

```
    from qiskit import QuantumCircuit, assemble, Aer
from qiskit.visualization import plot_histogram, plot_bloch_vector
from math import sqrt, pi

    ######################trying directly via circuit####################################
    qc = QuantumCircuit(3)  # Create a quantum circuit with one qubit
    initial_state = [0,1]   # Define initial_state as |1>
    qc.initialize(initial_state, 0) 
    qc.ry(-pi/2,0)
    qc.cx(0,1)
    qc.ry(pi/2,0)
    qc.cx(0,2)
    qc.ry(pi/2,0)
```

However, I've encountered an issue where the resulting state doesn't match the expected one.
[image]

I've experimented with the phase by incorporating a negative sign in the y-rotation,i.e ($ry(\pm pi/2,0)$) but I haven't been able to reproduce the state described in the paper. I've attempted all possible combinations with negatives, but none have yielded the desired outcome. It is so straightforward problem, I'm unsure about what I might be overlooking. It would be very if someone can say what I might be doing incorrectly